# Changing AnimationOverrideController "sometimes" fails - Unity 5.2.1

Tags: unity

I have the following code, in a menu where you can chose the armor and weapon of a character:

```
private List<string> armors = new List<string> { "armor1", "armor2", "armor2" };
private List<string> weapons = new List<string> { "weapon1", "weapon2", "weapon3", "weapon4", "weapon5", "weapon6", "weapon7", "weapon8", "weapon9" };

private int  armor_index = 0;
private int weapon_index = 0;

public GameObject avatar_body;
public GameObject avatar_weapon;

void Update() {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow)) nextArmor();
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))  previousArmor();
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))  nextWeapon();
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))    previousWeapon();
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))     loadLevel();
}

void nextArmor() {
    if (armor_index < armors.Count - 1)
        armor_index += 1;
    else
        armor_index = 0;

    setArmor();
    setWeapon();
}

void previousArmor() {
    if (armor_index > 0)
        armor_index -= 1;
    else
        armor_index = armors.Count - 1;

    setArmor();
    setWeapon();
}

void nextWeapon() {
    if (weapon_index < weapons.Count - 1)
        weapon_index += 1;
    else
        weapon_index = 0;

    setWeapon();
}

void previousWeapon() {
    if (weapon_index > 0)
        weapon_index -= 1;
    else
        weapon_index = weapons.Count - 1;

    setWeapon();
}

void setArmor() {
    avatar_body.GetComponent<Animator>().runtimeAnimatorController =
        Resources.Load("AnimationControllers/player/"+armors[armor_index]+"/body" ) as AnimatorOverrideController;
}

void setWeapon() {
    avatar_weapon.GetComponent<Animator>().runtimeAnimatorController =
        Resources.Load("AnimationControllers/player/"+armors[armor_index]+"/"+weapons[weapon_index] ) as AnimatorOverrideController;
}
```

The problem is when I start switching between the weapons, sometimes the sprite showing does not update. Inspecting the GameObject, it is weird, because the **Animator Component** has successfully updated, but the **Sprite Renderer** still shows a fixed sprite from the last Animator.

**Here are 2 examples:**

Here we see that the animator is set for the weapon **Gladius**, and that the **Sprite renderer** is looping through all the frames of that animation

[image]

Here we can see that even though we have moved to the **Flanged mace animator**, the **Sprite Renderer** is still stuck on a sprite of **Gladius**

[image]

The problem is hard to recreate, because it happens just **SOMETIMES**. If I were to switch back to **gladius** and then once again back to **flanged_mace**...

[image]

Now it works... but I didn't change anything.

What is going wrong??